# How to obtain the return value from a function enqueued in rq?

Tags: redis, queue, python-rq

From the documentation of redis queue https://python-rq.org/docs, I came to know that the worker can return results only after a certain time and till then return None.

Is there any way to find out that the worker execution is complete (not with time.sleep() pls.) ?

In my case what is happening is the worker keeps running and the data displayed on the UI is None as the control moves to my rendering of UI code as soon as worker is assigned the task and doesnot wait to complete the execution ?

Pls. help me.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a year, but if someone else needs it:

- that depends on your needs - I'd use supervisor, do you can easily see updated output of each running worker/process, either with the output file, or in the browser, with the [inet_http_server](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#inet-http-server-section-settings) section
- if you want something done, after the current job has finished - just chain jobs to the queue.
  you only need to specify the job in the "depends_on" parameter.[docs](https://python-rq.org/docs/#job-dependencies)